# access tab bar view controller in app globals

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

How do I access the tab bar view controller from app globals? The tab bar view controller is set up in storyboard. I dont want to create a new one but get the existing one.

Comment: I think it is not initiated @ that time. You can add a static variable and initialize it when the first view loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `UITabBarViewController` is set as the app's window `rootviewController`. If that's the case , you can get it like this:

```
AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[ [UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UITabBarViewController *myTabBarViewController = (UITabBarViewController *) myAppDelegate.window.rootViewController;
```

, where `AppDelegate` is the name of your App Delegate class.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

George